# How can I upload an image after verifying user data in Express.js?

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am trying to create a user profile in Express.js and MongoDB. I am using multer for image uploading. The Multer middleware always uploads the image before verifying my user data.

If user validation is failed, nevertheless image is uploaded. But, I want to upload an image after validating user data. That means, I will check user data in the controller, and if it is valid then I will upload image and store user data to MongoDB. How can I do that?

##### *multerConfig.js*

```
exports.multerConfig = (multer) => {
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: (req, file, cb) => {
            cb(null, './uploads/');
        },
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
            cb(null, 'img-' + new Date().toISOString() + '-' + file.originalname);
        }
    });

    const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
        (file.mimetype === 'image/png' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpg')
        ? cb(null, true)
        : cb(null, false)
    };

    return multer({
        storage: storage,
        limits: { fileSize: 1048576 },
        fileFilter: fileFilter
    });
};
```

##### *user.js* (Routes)

```
const multer = require('multer');
const express = require('express');
const userController = require('../controllers/user');
const { multerConfig } = require('../utility/multerConfig');
const validateObjectId = require('../middleware/validateObjectId');
const asyncErrorHandler = require('../middleware/asyncErrorHandler');

const router = express.Router();
const upload = multerConfig(multer);

router.post('/', upload.single('image'), asyncErrorHandler(userController.createUser));

module.exports = router;
```

##### **user.js* (Controller)

```
const { User, validate } = require('../models/user');

const { deleteFile } = require('../utility/fileUtility');
const { failed, success } = require('../utility/utility');

exports.createUser = async (req, res) => {
    const { error } = validate(req.body);
    if (error) return res.status(400).send({ ...failed, message: error.details[0].message });

    const { name, address, mobile, email, password } = req.body;

    if (!req.file) return res.status(400).send({ ...failed, message: `you have to upload an image!` });

    const isUserExist = await User.find().or([{ mobile }, { email }]);

    if (isUserExist.length > 0) return res.status(409).send({ ...failed, message: `${name} is already exists!` });

    const image = req.file.path;
    const newUser = new User({ name, address, mobile, email, password, image });
    const savedUser = await newUser.save();

    if (!savedUser) return res.status(500).send({ ...failed, message: `user ${name} is failed to save!` });

    res.send({
        ...success,
        data: savedUser,
        message: `user ${name} is saved successfully`
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use two `multer` middleware (one for parsing text, one for uploading your file).

Let's say you have a form with a `name` (text field) and `avatar` (file field), you can do this:

```
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');

var app = express();
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

app.post('/profile',
  upload.none(), function (req, res, next) {
    // validate `req.body.name` here
    // and call next(err) if it fails
    next();
  },
  upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
    // file is now uploaded, save the location to the database
    res.end('done!');
  });

app.listen(9000);
```